# Re-use the same search component in same template vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have normal search input witch will search and display some results. This is working fine, i need to clone this search input and re-use it again in the same component.

```
<input class="search ml-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" v-model="search">
```

The js:

```
 data() {
            return {
                hubs: [],
                search: '',
            }
        },
computed: {
    filteredList: function () {
        return this.hubs.filter((hub) => {
            return hub.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
        })
    }
},
```

My goal is to clone that search and show different result then the previous search, How can i do  that ? I might need to clone this search input more then twice.

The second seuch input would work independent, should return different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure if I'm following you, but I made an example showing what you probably want to do.

If you want it to be reusable it's better if you pass your array as a `prop` together with `key` in it's objects that's to be searched.

Below is an example with demo.

```
<div id="app">
<search :data="todos" search-key="text"></search>
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
          v-bind:checked="todo.done">

        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
<search :data="todos" search-key="text"></search>
</div>


Vue.component('search', {
    data() {
    return {
        userInput: '',
      results: []
    }
  },
  props: { data: Array, searchKey: String },
  template: `<div><input type="text" placeholder="Search..." v-model="userInput" class="form-control form-border-input" @input="search" />
<ul><li v-for="result in results">{{result.text}}</li></ul>
</div>`,
  methods: {
    search() { 
        this.results = this.data.filter(item => item[this.searchKey].toLowerCase().includes(this.userInput.toLowerCase()));
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/358621/

Comment: Yup this is what i need to have 2 or more inputs that would search independently, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a separate `search` property to hook up to the v-model of the second input.

You should probably also convert your computed `filteredList` property into a method that accepts a search query string. That way you can reuse it for both the inputs.

Comment: Any example for me ?